# How do I locate/import my plaid-python python module that has a dash?

Tags: python, plaid

```
$ pip install plaid-python
Requirement already satisfied: plaid-python in /Library/Python/2.7/site-
packages (3.4.0)
```

ok cool its installed.

```
>>> import plaid-python
import plaid-python
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

not installed.

```
>>>help('modules')
```

its not in the module list either.

Question:

- Is plaid-python truly installed?
- If yes how do I import it considering it contains a dash in its name?

Comment: Probably `import plaid_python` or `import plaid`, but it depends on the library. Look at its documentation. **Edit:** [Looks like `import plaid`](https://github.com/plaid/plaid-python#examples).

Comment: The name you tell `pip` to install isn't necessarily the same as the name you're supposed to import. Remember to check the docs.